# How do I get specific controller from AppDelegate

Tags: cocoa

I want to get reference on BaseController from AppDelegate.

My MainMenu.xib's hierarchy is

[image]

where BaseController is:

```
@interface BaseController : NSObject
```

I'm trying but I always get nil;

```
BaseController *base = (BaseController*)self.window.windowController;
```

Comment: Why are you not just connecting it in IB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an outlet for it in the app delegate and connect the controller to the outlet, as you would any other object (for example a button) in Interface Builder.

Then, in your app delegate, you can refer to it like this:

```
BaseController *base = self.windowController;
```

You don't need a cast if you already have declared the outlet to be of class `BaseController`.